# How can I save values from multiselect to the database in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-select, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-7

I've got a `has_many through:` relationship between two models: `achievements` (the parent) and `objectives` (the child), with `memberships` as my join.

I'm trying to add a multiselect subform for the child items into the parent form.  I can get the form to display correctly, but I'm missing the bit to actually save the association to the `memberships` table.  I'm finding tons of examples on how to make a subform that creates both the parent and *new* children at the same time, but I'm not trying to do that in my case.  I only want the user to select *existing* child items while creating or modifying a parent item.

I'm new to Rails, but I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental here.  I know I need to make changes to both the controller and the form, but how so?  Do I need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `achievements` model?  My attempts to play with that (while not really knowing what it does in this case) make my form break completely (the multiselect completely disappears).

Here are my three models:

```rb
class Achievement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :objectives, through: :memberships
end

class Objective < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :achievements, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :objective
  belongs_to :achievement
end
```

My form partial:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: achievement) do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
    <%= form.fields_for :objectives do |objectives_subform| %>
      <%= objectives_subform.label :objectives, "Objectives", style: "display: block" %>
      <%= objectives_subform.select :objectives, Objective.all.map{|o| [o.name]}, { }, multiple: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And finally, my controller:

```rb
class AchievementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_achievement, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /achievements or /achievements.json
  def index
    @achievements = Achievement.all
  end

  # GET /achievements/1 or /achievements/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /achievements/new
  def new
    @achievement = Achievement.new
    @achievement.objectives.build
  end

  # GET /achievements/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /achievements or /achievements.json
  def create
    @achievement = Achievement.new(achievement_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @achievement.save
        format.html { redirect_to achievement_url(@achievement), notice: "Achievement was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @achievement }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @achievement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /achievements/1 or /achievements/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @achievement.update(achievement_params)
        format.html { redirect_to achievement_url(@achievement), notice: "Achievement was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @achievement }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @achievement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /achievements/1 or /achievements/1.json
  def destroy
    @achievement.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to achievements_url, notice: "Achievement was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_achievement
      @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def achievement_params
      params.require(:achievement).permit(:name, objectives_attributes: [:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey If I understand properly, you're trying to create a `achievement` and you already have `objectives` data that you're rendering it inside form as dropdown as a multi select.

And while you do multi select for objectives dropdown you're going to send array of `objective id's` to the controller in the params and there you want to create `memberships` for `achievement` using the `objective id's`.

**If that's what you want to achieve here's how to do it in `controller`**

If you're receiving the array of `objective id's`

```
Ex:  [1,3,4,5]
```

**SOLUTION**

then you can create `memberships` for an `achievement` using the `objective ids` like this

In your case you're receiving the array of objective ids so do like this

```
@achievement.memberships.create(achievement_params[:objectives_attributes].map { |obj_id| { objective_id: obj_id }})
```

**In `controller` `create` action**

should look like this

```
 def create
   @achievement = Achievement.new(achievement_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @achievement.save
       @achievement.memberships.create(achievement_params[:objectives_attributes].map { |obj_id| { objective_id: obj_id }})
       format.html { redirect_to achievement_url(@achievement), notice: "Achievement was successfully created." }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @achievement }
     else
       format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       format.json { render json: @achievement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

**FUNDAMENTAL NOTES**

To access the memberships of an achievement

```
@achievement.memberships
```

To create one membership

```
@achievement.memberships.create(objective_id: 1)
```

To create n number of memberships using array of objective id's

```
@achievement.memberships.create([ { objective_id: 1 }, { objective_id: 2 } ])
```